# How to check transaction detail in Paypal API

Tags: php, node.js, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-rest-sdk

I have implementation paypal api use paypal node sdk for implementation checkout with paypal.
But how to check transaction detail as seller(account business) such as status transaction? I'll try to search in documentation paypal api, but I'm confused.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can call GetTransactionDetails API and TransactionSearch API to get transaction details.

GetTransactionDetails API
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetTransactionDetails_API_Operation_NVP/

TransactionSearch API
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/TransactionSearch_API_Operation_NVP/

PayPal Merchant SDK
https://github.com/paypal?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=merchant&type=&language=